# MYSQL Limit 1 Record per in Joined Table

Tags: mysql, join

Attempting to join two tables on `user_id`. The `users` table has unique `id` for each user. The `user_codes` table can have multiple rows with the same `user_id`. I only want to return 1 row from the joined `user_codes` table, where `code_count` is the largest.

**users Table**

```
| id       | email           |
| -------- | --------------- |
| 1        | user1@gmail.com |
| 2        | user2@gmail.com |
| 3        | user3@gmail.com |
```

**user_code TABLE**

```
| user_id  | invite_code | count |
| -------- | ----------- | ------|
| 1        | X49MCL1     | 40    |
| 1        | K59CLT9     | 1000  |
| 2        | X5BC924     | 15    | 
| 2        | 38DF80L     | 8     |
| 3        | 641020T     | 22    |
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
| id  |  email          | invite_code | count | 
| --- | --------------- | ----------- | ------|
| 1   | user1@gmail.com | K59CLT9     | 1000  |
| 2   | user2@gmail.com | X5BC924     | 15    |
| 3   | user3@gmail.com | 641020T     | 22    |
```

The `query result` only includes a single instance of each user found in the `user_codes` table with the highest `count`.

Here is the closest query I could get, but it only returns the `invite_code` and `count` for the first user.

```
SELECT a.id, a.email, b.invite_code, b.count
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN user_codes b
ON b.user_id = a.id 
AND b.count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM user_codes GROUP BY b.user_id)
```

The above query returns the result:

```
| id  |  email          | invite_code | count  | 
| --- | --------------- | ----------- | ------ |
| 1   | user1@gmail.com | K59CLT9     | 1000   |
| 2   | user2@gmail.com | `NULL`      | `NULL` |
| 3   | user3@gmail.com | `NULL`      | `NULL` |
```

I can't seem to figure out how/why the records after the first one don't include the `invite_code` and the `count`.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, I suggest using the `RANK()` window function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT u.id, u.email, uc.invite_code, uc.count,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY uc.count DESC) rnk
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN user_code uc
        ON uc.user_id = u.id
)

SELECT id, email, invite_code, count
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

The `RANK()` function will also match multiple records per user tied for the highest count.

You might be able to salvage your current attempt by correlating the user inside the subquery to the outer query:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.email, b.invite_code, b.count
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN user_codes b
    ON b.user_id = a.id AND
       b.count = (SELECT MAX(uc.count) FROM user_codes uc WHERE uc.user_id = a.id);
```

Comment: Still running 5.7 @tim-biegeleisen so the first option won't work, but second option did work. Thx.